# Chained apply return type seems determined at compile time

Tags: java, apache-beam

Can someone please explain the following lines of code to me:

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
[..]
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/*"))
.apply("ExtractWords", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {/* etc */}
```

What I don't get is why this compiles.
Apply method in Pipeline returns a T extends POutput.
Interface POutput does not have any apply method.

In this case, it just so happens that TextIO.read().from(...) returns a PCollection as POutput, and THAT has an apply method.

But as far as the Pipeline contract goes, we know that just a POutput will be returned.
So how does the compiler get to check the type of the argument passed to the first apply? From what I remember from when I was coding Java, that would be seen only at runtime.

Comment: Type T is known at compile time.

Comment: that would contradict what I think I knew - that at compile time T is replaced with it's bounded type - POutput in our case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature is:

```
public <OutputT extends POutput> OutputT apply(
    String name, PTransform<? super PBegin, OutputT> root) {
  ...
}
```

This means that, for any possible type `OutputT` that extends `POutput`, this method is applicable to `(String, PTransform<? super PBegin, OutputT>)` and returns `OutputT`.

`TextIO.read()` returns a `TextIO.Read` which extends `PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<String>>`; it matches `PTransform<? super PBegin, OutputT>`:

- The type `PBegin` is trivially a supertype of `PBegin`
- The type `PCollection<String>` extends `POutput`

So, the `.apply()` method is applicable, with the substitution `OutputT = PCollection<String>`. After substituting the actual value of `OutputT` into the signature of `.apply()`, the return value is `PCollection<String>`.

What you're saying (`OutputT` being replaced with `POutput`) happens during *type erasure* - the type-erased signature of `Pipeline.apply()` is `POutput apply(String, PTransform)`; and that is its signature in the compiled bytecode of `Pipeline` as far as the JVM is concerned when actually executing it. However, type erasure happens after type checking, not before - otherwise almost all Java programs using generics would fail to compile.

This is exactly the same thing that happens when you invoke `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)` - it returns a `List<Integer>` rather than `List<Object>` or `List`, even though the type-erased signature is `List asList(Object[])`.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that first there is explicit casting done and then type erasure is applied.
So checking the .class file, I see:
 18  invokevirtual org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform) : org.apache.beam.sdk.values.POutput [7]
    21  checkcast org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection [8]

[.... ]

36  invokevirtual org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(java.lang.String, org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform) : org.apache.beam.sdk.values.POutput [13]

so... you're right! Thanks!